# Opening multiple urls in browser using R and csv file

Tags: r, url, csv, browser

I want to open 4 sites using R, csv file and using functions

At present I can only open using variable in R for example

```
a <- "http://google.com"
b <- "http://yahoo.com"

browseURL(a) # this opens one tab
```

if i do --- `browseURL(a,b)` then it shows error

What I want to do is - save all my links in a csv column 
read it in R  and open all the links in the browser using For or While function

or any easier solution

if the script can also close the browser tab too.

Comment: `lapply(x1,browseURL)`? where `x1<-c(a,b)`

Comment: #Metrics, I like your solution because it doesn't use a loop, but I cannot seem to make it work using "a" and "b" defined as they are in the original question.  (I just copy/pasted your solution).  I get "unexpected symbol".  Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read contents of csv that contains url's in column A to a R data frame.

```
URL <- read.csv("D:/URL.csv", sep=",", header=T)
URL # View data frame
# Data table output is below
#                   URL
#1    http://google.com
#2     http://yahoo.com
#3 http://www.bing.com/
```

Loop through the data frame and open url in browser

```
# Option 1: Using for loop method
for (i in 1:nrow(URL)){
  browseURL(as.character(URL[i,1]))  
}

# Option 2: Using lapply
lapply(URL$URL,function(x) browseURL(as.character(x)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a music the first solution, awesome Manohar. Thanks a bucket.

Comment: It is saying I don't have points to mark up 1. Buggers. Anyways whoever go through this post can be sure that both suggestions work like a charm.

Comment: How does one insure that the multiple URLs are opened in tabs rather than separate instances of the browser?